# My code doesn't output the triple like it should. What could be the matter?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    system("title 세제곱, 나눗셈");

    int num1, num2, triple;
    float division;

    printf("정수값 2개 입력 : ");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

    triple = num1 * num1 * num1;
    printf("세제곱 연산 결과 : %08d", &triple);

    division - (float)num1 / num2;
    printf("나눗셈 연산 결과 : %8.3f", &division);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those '&' symbols mean something important, which is why they are needed when a function needs to change a var in the caller, like scanf, but not when just reading a value passed, like printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("나눗셈 연산 결과 : %8.3f", &division);` The `&` before the variable name means you are printing the address of the variable, not the value of it.

Try `printf("나눗셈 연산 결과 : %8.3f", division);`

You need the `&` in the `scanf_s`, but not in the `printf`s

Answer (score 0):

```
division - (float)num1 / num2;
```

I'm guessing this should be `division = (float)num1 / num2;`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
division - (float)num1 / num2;
```

Use assignment operator:

```
division = (float)num1 / num2;
```

And also the arguments for printf statement should not have `&` if you want to print their values:

```
printf("세제곱 연산 결과 : %08d", triple);
```